# output for hotkeys is different than expected

Tags: python, keyboard, hotkeys

I'm new to making python hotkeys.  I'm trying to use the python pypi keyboard module and I'm trying to get the lambda function to recognize keyboard entries.  I've also included a print statement to see if that works.  the print statement works but after that the keyboard entries bring back a none value.  how do i get the lambda function to recognize this part of the code? 
 Thanks for your help.

I've tried print, keyboard.write, I've tried to execute this through keyboard.press, and keyboard.press_and_release.

```
import keyboard


combination_to_function = {
    (keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+z', lambda: print("hotkey complete", keyboard.press('m')))), 
    (keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+x', lambda: print("hotkey complete", keyboard.press('f')))),
    (keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+v', lambda: print("hotkey complete", keyboard.press('o')))),
    (keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+d', lambda: print("hotkey complete", keyboard.press('k'))))
}

# Currently pressed keys
current_keys = set()

def on_press(key):
    # When a key is pressed, add it to the set we are keeping track of and check if this set is in the dictionary
    current_keys.add(key)
    if frozenset(current_keys) in combination_to_function:
        # If the current set of keys are in the mapping, execute the function
        combination_to_function[frozenset(current_keys)]()

def on_release(key):
    # When a key is released, remove it from the set of keys we are keeping track of
    current_keys.remove(key)

keyboard.wait()
```

The result was "hotkey complete" none.  I expected to get hotkey complete plus the letter pressed

Comment: `print("hotkey complete m")`

Comment: `press()` sends key to active window but it doesn't mean that it returns value to `print()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand problem but you can create function

```
def my_press(key):
    keyboard.press(key)
    print("hotkey complete", key)
```

and then use it

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+z', lambda: my_press('m'))
```